# Python Email Saving and Attachment Within An Attachment

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments, win32com, office-automation

As part of one of the processes we run we receive an email (in Outlook) that has a csv attachment within a .msg attachment that we need to save down.

I'm trying to save the .csv file but cannot figure out how to get to the attachment in the attachment. I am also brand new to Python so go easy on me. I have made the query generic but obviously the below only saves down the first attachment - I tried creating a variable for att.Attachment but that didn't work. HELP!

So far I have this:

```
import win32com.client
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import csv
import os

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application').GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages=inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

for i in list(messages):
    
    if "Hello" in str(i.subject):

        for att in i.Attachments:
            
            att.SaveAsFile(r'/C:/Users/el/Documents/' + att.FileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any methods for processing attached files beside saving them to the disk. So, you can save attached files to the disk by using the [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method. Then you you can open the saved files by automating their target applications, for example, the .msg file can be run to be opened in the default application (Outlook). In that case you will get a new `Inspector` window opened because Outlook is singleton, only one application can be run at the same time on the system. For the .csv file Excel can be automated to deal with a file content.